# Python overriding __init__

Tags: python

I know that plenty of people ask questions on this subject, but I haven't seen my specific one asked. When subclassing you can override `__init__()` the same way that you can override any other method. My question is why in the example below this doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
import random
class MyRand(random.Random):
    def __init__(self, myvar1, myvar2, x=None):
        # ( ... my code ...)
        super(MyRand, self).__init__(x)
```

Remember that `Random`'s constructor has the following signature: `__init__(self, x=None)` where `x` is an optional seed. I want to keep that feature in my subclass, but also I want to require two mandatory variables, `myvar1` and `myvar2`.

However, when you try and instantiate (without a seed) you get an error:

```
MyRand('var1', 'var2')
TypeError: seed expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

This is because python thinks you want `Random`'s constructor and passes your two arguments 'var1' and 'var2' as the seed. The seed (which is called from inside `Random`'s constructor) only wants 1 argument, and so you get an error.

However, if you do

```
MyRand(myvar1='var1', myvar2='var2')
```

This works, here python understands that you're passing it your two mandatory variables and not passing it the optional seed.

But I think the first case should work too. What's going on?

Comment: `super` in Python 3 haven't any necessary arguments.

Comment: @ADR: that's neither here nor there on this question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on that question...

Comment: Yes, I just read the answers. I stumbled across the same behaviour when inheriting `Exception`. Time to have a closer look to those obscure `__xxxx__` members.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What you said is true, but does not apply here. In my sample code, my `__init__` is never executed, and so `super` isn't either.

Comment: good question anyway. And I don't understand the duplicate thing. The answer of that other question is different and not even upvoted / accepted... Whatever, we have our answers now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python two methods are called when a object is created. `__new__` and `__init__`. Like many classes implemented in C, `random.Random` uses `__new__` to initialize itself (see [random_new](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_randommodule.c#l498)). You have to overwrite it and call it with the appropriate parameters:

```
import random

class MyRand(random.Random):
    def __new__(cls, myvar1, myvar2, x=None):
        return random.Random.__new__(cls, x)

    def __init__(self, myvar1, myvar2, x=None):
        # ( ... my code ...)
```

Comment: thanks. I'm going to mark yours as correct. But for the sake of completeness I would suggest that you edit your answer to contain the link that user2357112 mentioned. It's useful to see the real thing in addition to being given the answer.

Comment: `random.Random` itself doesn't implement a `__new__`; it's inheriting one from `_random.Random`. Note the underscore. `random.Random` implements an `__init__` method, making it really awkward to work with because you have to override both, and because the initialization order can get really weird.

Answer (score 8):

You've mis-diagnosed the problem a little. The problem is that `random.Random`'s initialization isn't entirely contained in `random.Random.__init__`. It also inherits [`_random.Random.__new__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_randommodule.c#l498):

```
static PyObject *
random_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    RandomObject *self;
    PyObject *tmp;

    if (type == &Random_Type && !_PyArg_NoKeywords("Random()", kwds))
        return NULL;

    self = (RandomObject *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
    if (self == NULL)
        return NULL;
    tmp = random_seed(self, args);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(self);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_DECREF(tmp);
    return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

You're going to have to override `__new__`, too, and only pass the `seed` argument it expects, positionally (because it doesn't understand it as a keyword argument).

They really shouldn't be mixing `__init__` and `__new__` like this. Initialization order gets really weird when you do that.

Comment: Is this because it's a class defined in the C or is it just a weird peculiarity of random?

Comment: @SeanMcSomething: Just a weird implementation detail of `random`.

Comment: @user2357112: no, most classes implemented in C behave like this.

Comment: @Daniel: Almost no classes behave like this, whether implemented in C or Python. Types like `list` and `dict` only set up an empty object in `__new__` and do all the initialization in `__init__`, while types like `tuple` and `int` do all the initialization in `__new__` and don't implement their own `__init__`. Almost no classes examine their arguments in both `__init__` and `__new__`.